# Cannot repair specific tables on specific nodes in Cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, cassandra-3.0

I'm running 5 nodes in one DC of Cassandra 3.10. 
As I'm trying to maintain those nodes I'm running on daily basis **on every node**

```
nodetool repair -pr
```

and weekly

```
nodetool repair -full
```

This is only table I have difficulties:

```
Table: user_tmp
        SSTable count: 4
        Space used (live): 366.71 MiB
        Space used (total): 366.71 MiB
        Space used by snapshots (total): 216.87 MiB
        Off heap memory used (total): 5.28 MiB
        SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.4690289976332873
        Number of keys (estimate): 1968368
        Memtable cell count: 2353
        Memtable data size: 84.98 KiB
        Memtable off heap memory used: 0 bytes
        Memtable switch count: 1108
        Local read count: 62938927
        Local read latency: 0.324 ms
        Local write count: 62938945
        Local write latency: 0.018 ms
        Pending flushes: 0
        Percent repaired: 76.94
        Bloom filter false positives: 0
        Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
        Bloom filter space used: 4.51 MiB
        Bloom filter off heap memory used: 4.51 MiB
        Index summary off heap memory used: 717.62 KiB
        Compression metadata off heap memory used: 76.96 KiB
        Compacted partition minimum bytes: 51
        Compacted partition maximum bytes: 654949
        Compacted partition mean bytes: 194
        Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 2.503074492537404
        Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 179
        Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
        Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1
        Dropped Mutations: 19 bytes
```

**Percent repaired** is never above 80% on this table on this and one more node  but on others is above 85%. RF is 3, and strategy is SizeTieredCompactionStrategy

gc_grace_period is on 10days and as I somewhere in that period I'm getting writetimeout on exactly this table but after consumer which got this timeout is immediately replaced with another one everything keep going like nothing happened. Its like one time writetimeout.

My question is: Are you maybe have suggestion for better repair strategy because I'm kind of a noob and every suggest is a big win for me + any other for this table?
Maybe `repair -inc` instead of `repair -pr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nodetool repair command in Casandra 3.10 defaults to running incremental repair. There have been some major issues with incremental repair and it's currently not recommended by the community to run incremental repair. Please see this article for some great insight into repair and the issues with incremental repair: http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2017/12/14/should-you-use-incremental-repair.html

I would recommend, as does many others, to run:

```
nodetool repair -full -pr
```

Please be aware that you need to run repair on every node in your cluster.  This means that if you run repair on one node per day you can have a max of 7 nodes (since with default gc_grace you should aim to finish repair within 7 days). And you also have to rely on that nothing goes wrong when doing repair since you would have to restart any failing jobs.

This is why tools like Reaper exist. It solves these issues with ease, it automates repair and makes life simpler. Reaper runs scheduled repairs and provides a web interface to make administration easier. I would highly recommend using reaper for routine maintance and nodetool repair for unplanned activities.

Edit: Link http://cassandra-reaper.io/

Comment: Thank you first of all!
Will you mind if I ask you two more question regarding repairs?
If if run for example `repair -full -seq` on one node. Do I need to run it on every node in cluster or one is good since it repairs all of the nodes in cluster? Is it ok to run `repair -pr` on every node in one day or you are suggesting node per day?

Aaand lasst one, I'm sorry for bothering :/, after repair full repair, I have tables drop from 75% repaired to 50% repaired, any clues maybe? Thank you very much!

Comment: You will always have to run repair on all nodes in the cluster (except for some special cases). The way repair works is that the repair node will always only repair data that it is replica of.

Comment: You can run repair on all nodes in parallell but it's highly recommended to only run repair one node at a time because of the high increase in cpu and io. And since full repair takes a long time to run and you don't want to run it during peak hours that usually only allows for one repair per day. But as with everything else you should test this for yourself and find the best approach for your use case. Perhaps performance is not as important for you and you are more interested in storing huge amount of data then you can do more repairs per day.

Comment: The "percent repaired" only shows for how much of data was repaired with incremental repair so it should never increase by doing full repair. However, it shouldn't decrease either. Perhaps you're inserting a lot of data which increase the amount of unrepaired data?

Comment: If I understood well `repair -full -seq` should be run on all of the nodes in cluster?
Well, I'm not inserting soem huge amount, its about 80k per hour.

Comment: Yes, `repair -full -seq` also has to be run on all nodes in the cluster.

Comment: Ok, thank you man I will take this as answer on my question :)

Comment: But, how do you know then if your tables are repaired or not if as you said "percent repaired" shows only how much of the data was repaired with incremental repair?

Comment: @Superbrain_bug Every SSTable is either repaired or unrepaired. When it's repaired it contains a repairedAt flag to show when the data was repaired. You can see this for a SSTable using the sstablemetadata tool. I haven't looked at the code but I assume the percent repaired is simply showing how many sstables are marked with this (and maybe even counting how much data it contains to get a more exact value).

Comment: Should I run compaction after repair maybe?